# I cant get all HTML with Python Requests

Tags: python

```
import requests as req

html = req.get(url)
texto = html.text
print(texto)
```

I cant get all HTML with Python Requests, only gets a litle part from the html file.

Comment: Hello, please share the url you are looking after.

Comment: https://servidor.aternos.me/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `headers` to your request to obtain a response like in your browser. Try:

```
import requests as req

headers = {
    'Host': 'servidor.aternos.me',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cookie': 'axcaccess=e75a91ffeda624d3a1e24c1d9fb31734',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1'
}
url = 'https://servidor.aternos.me/'
html = req.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=10.)
print(html.status_code)
texto = html.text
print(texto)
```

Comment: Still without giving me the part of the body I want, just happens with this page